# Why bother using Apache or Nginx, etc?

Tags: c++, c, webserver

I've been assigned a project which requires me to add some HTML page serving. This embedded system (running Linux CentOS 6.3) has some extra juice available, but also already has numerous responsibilities.

I considered Apache but tossed it due to bloat, I looked into Nginx but am now shying from that too. It just seems that I'm getting way more 'functionality' and as a result, more CPU usage than I need.

Can someone enlighten me as to why I wouldn't just implement the HTTP protocol myself using async sockets?

My specific needs are:

1. Receive and decode GETs and POSTs.
2. Send CSS, JS and JPG files as requested.
3. Output header, cookie, head and body data based upon the decode of the GETs/POSTs.

Given that I don't need the myriad things these webservers offer, am I being naive in assuming this course of doing it myself? What would you suggest or warn against?

Comment: For really basic implementations, sure. Just be wary of security risks that you are not as good at mitigating as existing web servers are.

Comment: The challenge of getting it right, especially if there is security exposure.  But there are smaller embedded webservers you could look at.

Comment: If you only have to implement a small subset of GET and POST it is pretty straightforward to do from scratch.

Comment: You'd essentially write your own web server. Why would you do that? It's a lot harder than using an existing one. What massive benefits do you expect that outweighs that cost?

Comment: The time taken to implement your own web server, even basic, and to fix all the bugs and vulerabilities could buy you a farm of servers ready to serve your HTML pages with a well-tested, supported web server.

Comment: With nginx, you choose the modules you want when you compile it. It can be as small as you want it to be.

Comment: If you want a light-weight webserver and still don't want to write everything yourself, you might want to consider forking an open-source project and removing things you don't need for your own needs.

Comment: I appreciate the answers! Given the responses, I will go forward with doing this myself. Frankly, each of the web servers has an impressive list of bugs and issues that I feel would take just as much time to learn as implementing simple HTTP myself. I'm not intimidated by either text parsing or protocols - both are of special interest to me. Thanks again!

Comment: I just finished it. The worst part was just getting over what a horrible "protocol" http is. Looks like it was developed by amateurs, not experienced protocol designers (like the old Bell Labs). They really screwed up on the "multipart" boundary idea. Each multipart has its own headers, but they decided to not use Content-Length in lieu of a boundary scan-idiocy. I'm astounded by how many CPU cycles world-wide and daily are wasted decoding this sophomoric protocol. HTTP designers need to learn what it means to separate layers of a protocol and that binary data is superior to text.

Comment: @GarysTampaOffice OfficeTampa how much code was it? Just curious...

Comment: The final server with the basics (get, put, head) and file upload (multi-part posts) ended up compiling to about 50K with everything I needed including a small website. It really wasn't a lot of work. GCC 4, CentOS 6.3, 64-bit.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you use a web server because then you get the functionality you want in a form that's already been tested, is more reliable than your first code is likely to be, and is supported by a large community of others.  If Apache and nginx are too heavyweight for you (although nginx is pretty much characterized by how lightweight it is for heavy loads) and especially if the load you expect is very light, then look around for other options.

Wiki has a whole page of [comparisons of lightweight web servers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers)

Comment: In the five years since I answered this, another option has appeared: using Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

An easy trap to fall into: thinking "I don't need all the functionality in Product X, I'll just write my own with just the functionality that I need" only to end up reimplementing Product X entirely, one newly-discovered requirement at a time.

I sort of doubt that an embedded system that can run CentOS okay is so resource-starved that it can't run Nginx comfortably (or even Apache, which people run on the Raspberry Pi just fine with appropriate configuration tweaks), given reasonable assumptions about how many pages you are actually serving. I ran it on a Pentium 266 with something like 256MB of RAM serving a few simple PHP apps that served roughly a page every two seconds, with no issues. As I recall, it's fairly modular, so you can just choose not to load the functionality you don't think you need. And, later, when your requirements change and you find out you do need it, you can just plug it back in :)

If you are really and truly concerned about resource consumption, look into web servers designed for embedded applications. I hear [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) is quite nice. [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) looks promising as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go further you can, I began with this http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTTP2.html